# C# LINQ Statement for the Below Scenario

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to build a LINQ Statement for Joining the below two list in C#.

List1:

```
FormID  FormRound
2        1
2        2
2        3
3        1
4        2
```

List2:

```
FormID  FormRound   Category    Date
2           1        Test1     23-Aug
2           1        Test2     24-Aug
2           1        Test3     25-Aug
2           2        Test1     26-Aug
2           2        Test3     27-Aug
3           1        Test1     28-Aug
3           1        Test2     29-Aug
3           1        Test3     30-Aug
```

I should get the Output as below.

```
FormID  FormRound   Test1Date   Test2Date   Test3Date
2          1          23-Aug    24-Aug       Test3
2          2          26-Aug    NA           27-Aug
3          3          28-Aug    29-Aug       NA
```

Can anyone please help me in Framing the LINQ Statement?

Comment: Your list format is hard to read, could you use another delimiter and wrap it in code block for more readability?

Comment: The first entry under your `Test3Date` column should surely be `25-Aug` and not `Test3`, correct? And the `FormRound` for `FormID = 3` should be `1` and not `3`, right? Aaand the last date under `Test3Date` should then be `30-Aug`, right? If not, then your results are impossible.

Comment: What is `List1` for? From what I see, your output can be made by only using `List2`. I also noted the inconsistencies @Cᴏʀʏ named.

Comment: @Das: I answered this only because I wanted to see if I could figure it out. It's being downvoted because you have not shown any effort yourself. A better question would include some code that you've tried yourself, any errors or intermediate data you have.

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ query might look like:

```
var results = (from a in list1
               join b in list2 on new { a.FormId, a.FormRound } equals new { b.FormId, b.FormRound }
               group b by new { a.FormId, a.FormRound } into c
               select new 
               {
                   c.Key.FormId,
                   c.Key.FormRound,
                   Test1Date = c.Where(d => d.Category == "Test1").Select(e => e.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Test2Date = c.Where(d => d.Category == "Test2").Select(e => e.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Test3Date = c.Where(d => d.Category == "Test3").Select(e => e.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
               });
```

Which, using your sample data, produces:

```
2   1   23-Aug  24-Aug  25-Aug
2   2   26-Aug  null    27-Aug
3   1   28-Aug  29-Aug  30-Aug
```

This is not exactly your expected results, but I think you have some issues with what you're expecting based on my comments on your question.

Comment: Is joining `list1` useful at all?

Comment: It is, because `list1` has entries for `FormId` = 4, which are not in `list2`. The join filters those out.

Comment: Exactly, ignoring `list1` doesn't change a thing. Maybe if `list1` didn't have `2 - 2` and that made the second row not appear in the results, then it would have some use.

Comment: @Cory, I am really sorry for the late Response. The Output which you produces is the same which I am expecting.  As I am new to LINQ and Just started working on this, I could not provide any sample code...really sorry for that... would do some research from my end and then post the question in future.... Thank You SO much !!!